# Making a Git alias out of a working Git command... unsuccessful

Tags: git, shell, configuration, alias

I do have a command that works for showing the Git history of a file:

```
$ git show --oneline -s $(git rev-list HEAD -- 32-factures-creation.R)
0df507b9 Simplify SQL expression in 32-factures-creation.R
16f94a10 Update format of prsAnneeMois
f9a6cafb Update "Facturation à l'employeur"
74cb7d3e Add ISNULL conditions
29d4886c Add new key prsNbrJTad, and modify Excel sheet, screens and scripts
da3c94a1 Merge branch 'bugfix/87-fraction-horaire-sur-facture' into release/20.09
...
```

I'd like to make an alias out of it.

But if I'm using my alias:

```
file-history-f = "!f() { git show --oneline -s $(git rev-list HEAD -- $1); }; f"
```

then I just have *one line* outputted:

```
$ g file-history-f 32-factures-creation.R
f2e32231 (HEAD -> stgid-en-lecture-seule, origin/stgid-en-lecture-seule) Add stgIDReadOnly_vk
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...  The contents between the brackets is exactly what does work, when executed from the command line, with the file name being replaced by `$1`...

Any idea?

BTW, my other alias:

```
file-history-sh = !sh -c 'git show --oneline -s $(git rev-list HEAD -- $1)'
```

It does output *everything*, like a non-filtered log output:

```
$ g file-history-sh 32-factures-creation.R
f2e32231 (HEAD -> stgid-en-lecture-seule, origin/stgid-en-lecture-seule) Add stgIDReadOnly_vk
e89bc4b1 (origin/master, master) Revert "Rebuild wars"
907e500a Rebuild wars
b18b8eb6 Index amounts in DocuContratCFI
d5590007 Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/.../...
6ccde740 Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/.../...
```

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use `git log` ? `git log --oneline -- <filename>` ; you can alias `log --oneline` as a regular git command : `lone = log --oneline`

Comment: I actually have the following alias : `lol = log --graph --oneline`, which I use all the time

Comment: @LeGEC, that might be a pertinent question... I should check if there are differences between both techniques... Very interesting.

Comment: Though, my "misunderstanding" about what goes wrong here does stay: why can't I create an alias the way I do?

Comment: @user3341592 That being said, I tried your alias and I have the same output as the unaliased command. Could it be something with your filepath? Maybe double-quote the param : `git config --global alias.file-history-f '!f() { git show --oneline -s $(git rev-list HEAD -- "$1"); }; f'` or just quote the argument you pass to your alias, for a try.

Comment: @user3341592 : I agree about the alias issue, that's why I didn't post it as an answer :D FWIW : your alias works on my machine (git 2.34, ubuntu 21.04). What's your git version / OS ? (and possibly : what shell is used as `sh` ?)

Comment: My best guess here would be that you have a "bad" (non-POSIX) shell installed as `/bin/sh`. Some Linux systems use dash for instance, although dash probably should work here. Tracing the commands, with GIT_TRACE and strace and similar, might be informative.

Comment: OP, I just tried your alias, it works fine. You've got something hinky going on somewhere, something that got lost between your system and your question body. The first thing I see as a possibility is the unquoted  `$1`, though your example shows no whitespace so that doesn't seem right.  But on thinking about it, it's also possible you've somehow got a shell that doesn't wordsplit command expansions by default. @torek's suggestion looks really good for this, what do you get when you say `/bin/sh --version`? p.s. try `strace -feexecve g file-history-f 32-factures-creation.R`

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the alias to this:

```
file-history-f = "!f() { git show --oneline -s $(git rev-list HEAD -- $0); }; f"
```

Note the `$0` instead of `$1`.  That's because when you use the `!` syntax in a Git alias, it gets invoked with `sh -c`, and with `sh -c`, the first argument is `$0`, not `$1`.  This is a quirk of POSIX shell, and it applies here as well.